# Как вызвать Activity методом startActivityForResult не из другого Activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Здравствуйте, у меня есть класс логики (Test), из которого необходимо вызвать другое Activity методом startActivityForResult (Или каким-то другим образом получить информацию из запускаемого Activity).

```
public class Test {
private ArrayList<Question> questions;
private Context context;

public Test(Context context, ArrayList<Question> questions) {
    this.questions = questions;
    this.context = context;
}

public Test(Context context, Question... questions) {
    for (Question question : questions) {
        this.questions.add(question);
    }
    this.context = context;
}

public void addQuestion(Question question) {
    questions.add(question);
}

public double testing() throws Exception {
    Question[] array = new Question[questions.size()];
    array = questions.toArray(array);
    Main.shake(array);
    int result = 0;
    for (Question question : array) {
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.gopea_system.phisickgame.game.test");
        intent.putExtra("isTest", true);
        intent.putExtra("com.gopea.QuestionsID", question.getID());
        //context.startActivityForResult(intent,1); // it's doesn't work???
        context.startActivity(intent);
        int getScore = 0;
        if (getScore != -1000) {
            result += getScore;

        } else {
            throw new Exception("Incorrect return to Test.testing");
        }

        Log.d("Gopea"," now result = " + result);
    }

    return result / (array.length * 100);
}
}
```

В методе testing() необходимо запустить Activity и узнать значение (результат), которое должно быть возвращено в класс Test. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: "Activity методом startActivityForResult не из другого Activity" - с фрагмента?

Answer (score 1):

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    ((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(intent, resultCode);
```

Comment: Дайте более развёрнутй ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Для запуска активности вам нужно в метод `testing()` или в конструктор класа `Test` нужно передать текущий контекст. Для получение значения с другой активности имеет смысл использовать `startActivityForResult`.Пример:

Запускаем нужную активность `SecondActivity`

```
public static final REQUEST_CODE = 1; 
public static final REQUEST_ID = "some_id";

Intent intent = new Intent(context, SecondActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

В активности которую запустили нужно вернуть интент.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra(REQUEST_ID, some_variable);
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
finish();
```

И принимаем результат с помощью `onActivityResult`

```
  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (data == null) {return;}
    String text = data.getStringExtra(REQUEST_ID);
  }
```

Для примера получал текст но интент имеет методы для получения и других типов.Удачи!